# How does the ps command work?

Tags: linux, ps

For an assignment I need to implement my own version of the `ps` command, but I'm not sure where it gets its information from. Where do I look to find all process information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux, the `ps` command works by reading files in the [proc filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux). The directory `/proc/PID` contains various files that provide information about process *PID*. The content of these files is generated on the fly by the kernel when a process reads them.

You can find documentation about the entries in `/proc` in the [proc(5) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

You can find this out by yourself by observing what the `ps` command does with [`strace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), a command that lists the system calls made by a process.

```
% strace -e open ps
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/self/stat", O_RDONLY)       = 3
open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY)          = 3
open("/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY)         = 4
open("/proc/1/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 6
open("/proc/1/status", O_RDONLY)        = 6
open("/proc/2/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 6
open("/proc/2/status", O_RDONLY)        = 6
open("/proc/3/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 6
open("/proc/3/status", O_RDONLY)        = 6
…

% strace -e open ps
…
open("/proc/1/stat", O_RDONLY)          = 6
open("/proc/1/status", O_RDONLY)        = 6
open("/proc/1/cmdline", O_RDONLY)       = 6
…
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look in the `/proc` folder:
Every process running on your machine has a subfolder here, with plenty of files (the most useful IMO being `comm`, that gives the name of the process.)

Comment: There is no entry `comm` in my `/proc/pid`. There is an `exe` pointing to the executable. Much more useful is `/proc/pid/status`.

Comment: oh yes, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

It works by using libprocps.so library.

The main format is :

(A) start (calling openproc())

(B) reading info of process (calling readproc() for each one)

(C) stop ( calling closeproc())

Using libprocps.so gives advantages (for example, freeing you of coding a bunch of "parsing" functions) and disadvantages (maybe you want less info than gathered by readproc() calls).

A program using libprocps.so has this basic format.

```
    #include <proc/readproc.h>
         :
    int main()
   {
         :
       PROCTAB *proctab = openproc(<OPTIONS>) ;
         :
         :
       proc_t procinfo ;
       memset(&procinfo, 0, sizeof(procinfo)) ;
       while(readproc(proctab, &procinfo) != nullptr)
       {
          <do something with procinfo data>
       }
         :
         :
       closeproc(proctab) ;
       return 0 ;
    }
```

procinfo will hold all info for a process(like utime, stime, priority, nice, ppid, etc) already in numeric format. If you downloaded the sources, **proc_t** struct is defined into readproc.h

The **OPTIONS** you can use in the openproc() call are bitwise-or flags, so you can use one or more of then, as :

```
    PROCTAB *proctab = openproc(PROC_FILLMEM | PROC_FILLCOM) ;
```

They are defined into readproc.h too (search for '#define PROC_FILLMEM').

Comment: That's true, but not very interesting. It's just a detail of how ps is packaged: the code of libprocps and of ps come from the same source tree. The interesting part is how the functions in libprocps work.

Comment: As all responses are about /proc, I posted another alternative. No problem if he wants collect data reading files from /proc. But if he only wants do something with these data that ps doesn't, using the lib is the fastest way to go.